# Define site.title in a Jekyll template

Tags: templates, jekyll

## My Problem

I am building a Jekyll static site using the [jekyll-materialize-starter-template](https://github.com/macrod68/jekyll-materialize-starter-template).

The home page contains an `h1` title in the front center:

[image]

Which reads `Your awesome title`, and defined in `_layouts/home.html`:

```
<h1 class="header center orange-text">{{ site.title }}</h1>
```

How can I set the value of `site.title`?

## What have I tried

- Searched for `site.title` and `title`
- Read the [docs about variables](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/)
- Hard-code my title. Works, but it feels like the wrong thing to do - variables should be properly set.

## My question

**How can I set the `site.title` variable used by a Jekyll template?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit `_config.yml` and locate the `title` key:

```
title: Starter Template
```

or

```
title: Your awesome title
```

and change that value.

If you are developing with a local server, restart the jekyll server to reflect changes to config.